# How do I distinguish between activity controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I saw this code on NSHipster, but how does it get called?

```
- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController
     itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType

if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook]) 
{
    return @"Like this!";
    } else if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter]) {
        return @"Retweet this!";
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

I found it here: http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/

I also have this called:

```
- (void) shareFunction

NSString *textTitle = @"Hello";
NSString *text2 = _@"world";
UIImage *bestPhoto = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: _photoData];
NSURL *website = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"];

NSArray *objectsToShare = @[textTitle, bestyText, bestPhoto, website];

NSArray *includeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeMessage,
                               UIActivityTypeMail,
                               UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,
                               UIActivityTypePostToTwitter,
                               UIActivityTypePostToFlickr];


UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                               UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                               UIActivityTypePrint,
                               UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                               UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                               UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                               UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                               UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];

activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: it works when you add Facebook and Twitter sharing to an iOS app.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityItemSource_protocol/index.html

Comment: I did but on my iphone 6 facebook didn't say like this!

Comment: you need to configure your facebook account from settings.

Comment: See code above. It does post to facebook but the like this! doesn't